# How to pass a prop to ReactNode Object being rendered using map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, user-interface, redux

```
function fun(){
    const [contentArray,setContentArray] = useState([]);
    setContentArray([...contentArray, <A />]);
    setContentArray([...contentArray, <A />]);
    setContentArray([...contentArray, <A />]);
    return(
      <div>
      {
        contentArray.map( (component:React.ReactNode,i:number) => {
          return(
            component
          )}
      }
      </div>
     })
   );
}
```

above code works fine as long as i dont want to pass any prop to these array elements of "contentArray" array.but i want to pass indexes as props to these array elements
code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-cray-u4jr1?from-embed

Comment: `contentArray.map( (Component:Function,i:number) => {
return(
   <Component key={i} />
   );
})`?

Comment: @zerkms variable "component" inside map hold a react function component, wouldnt <Component key = {i}/> try to look for a function component named "Component"?

Comment: see that I renamed the anonymous function argument as well.

Comment: @zerkms oh thanks, let me try

Comment: got this error "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

Comment: Update your question with your current code

Comment: So, previously you told that `contentArray` holds **functions**, but you put there objects - `<A/>` --- this is an object

Comment: I posted explanations to a chat that you originally created then removed https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202831/discussion-between-nikhil-kekan-and-zerkms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while setting the state it should be done as below

`setState(prevState => [...prevState, A]`

and while rendering it it should b rendered as below

`{state.map((Comp, i) => {
        return <Comp key={i} index={i} />;
      })}`

Note: no need to specify type as React.ReactNode, and you need to lookout for not setting state inside render, react doesn't allow it, in order to avoid infinite loop.

Thanks for showing way to do it @bpas247
`https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-flower-z87mt`